# "The man who has smoked a lot" – change to adjective phrase?

Tags: phrases, adjectives, clauses

Often, if we have a noun modified by a relative clause, we can substitute an adjectival (participial) phrase for the relative clause:

> A man who collects newspapers → A *newspaper-collecting* man

But how do we do that if the relative clause is in the perfect aspect? For example:

> The man who has smoked a lot → The _____ man

How can we create a corresponding adjectival phrase to modify *man* corresponding to the relative clause in this case?

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'What is the tense of that present perfect'?  'Present perfect' of course!

Comment: You can’t. Not in English. You could translate it into Clasiccal Greek, then it would be a piece of cake (à la _ὃ πολλὰ καπνὶσας ἄνθρωπος_), but that might be a bit extreme…

Comment: "The chain smoker..."?

Comment: Give us a concrete example of what you mean by "changing the adj. clause to adj. phrase" I might say: "*That* man is a heavy smoker"

Comment: Without changing the sentence ...about this sententense....how can I say that without "who"???

Comment: A reduced phrase might be "The heavy smoker [went out and bought himself another packet.]"

Comment: @Mari-Lou Consider how “The man who builds houses” can be transformed into “The house-building man”, by replacing the relative clause with a participle. This question is asking how to do the same for “The man who has built the house”, which is unfortunately not possible in English: “The house-having-built man” is completely nonsensical. Hence my jab about Classical [which should not have been ‘Clasiccal’, of course, ahem] Greek, where such constructions are exceedingly common, using aorist and perfect participles.

Comment: I’ve edited the question to make it clear what’s actually being asked.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Oh, thank you for explaining. So my earlier suggestion "heavy smoker" didn't really cut the mustard so to speak. It's only an idiomatic expression.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from the question how the requested word is to be used, but where a word [doesn't really exist in English](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g) it may be appropriate to appropriate a related expression:

> The **well-smoked** man

This is perhaps slightly humorous as it treats the man as a kipper. It wouldn't work in every situation.

A better solution is simply to say that the man is a *smoker*: unless the distinction between a particular man and woman is important, you may not need to use the word *man* at all.

> The **heavy smoker**